# Unable to start etcd service ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, kubernetes

I have installed etcd but when I run it's service following error appears.

**Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused**

I tried commands like;

```
$ sudo initctl start etcd
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

$ sudo start etcd
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

None of these two worked for me. Could anyone tell me how may I start etcd in ubuntu 16.04.3 because the second command worked for me in ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Did you check the log files?

Comment: 16.04 uses `systemctl`. How did you install etcd?

Comment: I also tried systemctl but it says; Failed to start etcd.service: Unit etcd.service not found.

Comment: I installed etcd using this link https://github.com/openstack/gluon/blob/master/doc/source/installation/install_etcd.rst

Comment: I have installed etcd using this [link](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/releases/) and I could start etcd service successfully.